# Getting unique col values based on condition in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

**Input:**

```
IP    Flag
101   Yes
101   Yes
101   No
103   Yes
103   Maybe
103   Yes
104   No
104   Yes
```

How can I get a list of unique IPs that have a flag of Yes and No?

**Expected Output:**

```
IP
101
104
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reshape your dataset with `pd.crosstab`, grab only 'No' and 'Yes' columns and check which rows have no 0's at all:

```
m = pd.crosstab(df['IP'],df['Flag'])[['No','Yes']].ne(0).all(1)
print(m)

IP
101     True
103    False
104     True
dtype: bool

print(m[m].index.tolist())
[101, 104]
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to `groupby` and aggregate a custom function:

```
mask = df.groupby('IP')['Flag'].agg(lambda x: {'Yes','No'} <= set(x))
mask.index[mask]
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([101, 104], dtype='int64', name='IP')
```